# How to track changes in figures?

Tags: latexdiff, changes

I'm using [latexdiff](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff) to track changes between two version of a manuscript, which is working fine. I also need to track changes in figures that I include through [includegraphics](https://ctan.org/pkg/graphics).

In other words, for

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello world!
\includegraphics{somefig}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello brave new world!
\includegraphics{somefig-v2}
\end{document}
```

I would like the output of [latexdiff](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff) - or of some alternative - to not just highlight the added "brave new", but also to indicate in some way, e.g., through change bars in the margin, that the figure has changed.

The manual of [changes](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/changes/changes.english.pdf) (version 4.2.1 of July 15, 2021) states in Section 6.1 that figures cannot be marked.

Can I get [latexdiff](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff) to do what I want? If not, are there any other packages or tools that can do what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work out of the box. Check out the option `--graphics-markup` of latexdiff. By default, the example above should show the figure with a blue frame around.
Note that latexdiff only looks at the command and does not consider the content of the graphics file. So in your example it would work as "somefig-v2" is different from "somefig" but it would not notice if somefig itself is changed (e.g. when comparing files in different directories). Also, if options to includegraphics are being used, a change in the options will make the figure appear to be changed to latexdiff.

With `--graphics-markup=both`  the old figure would be shown with a red cross-out superimposed. This has the potential to disrupt the formatting so is turned off by default.

Comment: Thanks, does exactly what I need. I don't know how I missed this in the manual...